# Why can't I boot Ubuntu?

Tags: boot

I have to two operating systems in my computer. Ubuntu in D drive and windows 7 in C drive.
Now I replaced window 7 with window 8 but I can't load both the windows simultaneously..
how I can resolve this problem??

Comment: As it stands, your question is ambiguous. Is the problem that you cannot load both *Windows* systems, or that you cannot load both Windows 8 and Ubuntu? Either way, what happens when you try?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand after the windows 8 installation, now you cant boot ubuntu because the grub menu disappeared. All you need to do is re-install the grub.  you can do it by creating a bootable USB  using *wubi*. There are lots of tutorials in the web, If you want more assistance please ask below.